# Trying to install Lubuntu 14.04 on Dell Dimension 2300

Tags: lubuntu, dell

I tried to install on Dell computer. This computer achieves an internet connection via Windows XP, however does not with Lubuntu.

Before I perform the full install, I'd like to make sure it is connected to the internet.  Perhaps the full install will solve the problem?

Comment: Is this wifi or wired?

Comment: I have an ethernet hub here.  Signal is good on another computer.  We have internet using WinXP on the Dell.  I have installed Lubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo ThinkCentre, however the Dell is a different story.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu 14.04 was released with a bug that did not start the nm-applet.  It has been fixed. However, if you are trying to install 14.04, you must physically start the network manager.  To do that go to Menu->Preferences->Default applications for LXsession->Autostart
Navigate to Add and type in nm-applet.  Then tap Add.  I believe that you have to log out and back in for it to take effect.  Once you get on the Internet, one of the updates will fix that bug.

Comment: After I add the nm-applet, do I just restart the computer?  I don't see an exit from the dialog box.  Thank you.

Comment: Just close it.  There is no save box.

Comment: Thank you Rex.  I got myself into a pickle now after trying this.  I attempted a full install of Lubuntu 14.04 and the installation crashed and the hard drive is wiped out.  Upon further attempts to install, I get the message 'unable to find a medium containing a live file system.'   Thanks for your feedback.     Hank